# View Controller reloading instead of dismissing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a view controller, that modally presents a navigation controller. The navigation controller has 2 view controllers.

Each of these 3 view controllers are delegated in a chain.

The top most view controller, VC3, I want to dismiss all the way back to the view controller that presented the navigation controller, VC1.

So in VC3 I call to my delegate which is VC2

```
[self.delegate newGameViewController:self submitRound:nil forGame:self.game];
```

VC2 reacts

```
-(void)newGameViewController:(NewGameViewController *)newGameViewController submitRound:(NSDictionary *)round forGame:(Game *)game
{
    NSLog(@"Delegate Called");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.delegate turnViewController:self didCompleteTurnWithStats:[self statsWithOutcome:_wonTurn]];

}
```

This should pop the top view of the navigation controller, which is VC3. Then call its delegate which is VC1 - which presented the UINavigationController

In VC1

```
-(void)turnViewController:(TurnViewController *)turnViewController didCompleteTurnWithStats:(NSDictionary *)stats
{
     [self.turnNav dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
         [self updateData];
     }];
}
```

This should dismiss the entire navigation controller, and VC1 should be the visible view controller.

But THIS IS NOT THE CASE.

Instead, it reloads a new instance of VC3.

This only happens when the phone locks whenever VC3 is visible and then is reopened, or the app is switched to the background and back. I followed Apple's guidelines of only dismissing view controllers by the controllers that presented them - but it still appears that my presenting controllers are being deallocated? At least thats what I am assuming is happening.

Is there anyway to prevent this? I tried registering for notifications for name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification to try and dismiss before this happens - but it only triggers half the time.

Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code of my updateData method in VC1 - that is called before dismissing the navigation controller. I updated the code to call it after the navigation controller had been dismissed. No change to the problem.

```
-(void)updateData
{
    [[GameManager instance] getGame:self.game withCompletion:^(Game *game, BOOL completed){
    if(completed)
    {
        if(game.played){
            [self loadGameComplete];
        } else {
            if(!roundsLoaded)
                [self shouldLoadRounds];

            if(UILoaded && roundsLoaded)
                [self updateUI];

            if(self.game.lastTurn.played && self.game.myTurn)
                [self shouldSendPhoto];
        }
    } else {
        if(!roundsLoaded)
            [self loadError];
    }
}];
}
```

EDIT 2: I am now explicitly dismissing the navigation controller, which I have a strong reference too, in VC1. Still reloading VC3 instead of dismissing.

Here is my method in VC1 that loads the navigation controller with VC2 as the root.

```
-(void)loadTurn:(Turn *)turn
{
    if(turn.played){ [self shouldSendPhoto]; return; }

    TurnViewController *turnVC = [[TurnViewController alloc] initWithGame:self.game andTurn:turn];
     turnVC.delegate = self;
     self.turnNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:turnVC];
     self.turnNav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
     if(IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS)
         self.turnNav.navigationBarHidden = YES;

     [self presentViewController:self.turnNav animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: can you show the code of updateData ?

Comment: updated the post. also moved the call to the method to the completion block of the nav controller dismiss - same problem.

Comment: If VC1 is the one that presented the navigation controller, then you should just have [self dismiss...] not [self.navigationController dismiss...] in VC1. VC1 shouldn't even have a non-nil navigationController property unless you have another navigation controller that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @rdelmar - I took your advice. However it did not solve my problem. I made a strong reference to the Navigation controller I was presenting and now explicitly dismiss it. VC3 is still reloading instead of dismissing. I including my method from VC1 on how I display the Navigation Controller which contains VC2 as its root.

Comment: I have no idea how it's possible for the code you show to create a new instance of VC3. Are you making these controllers in a storyboard? If so, can you post an image of it somewhere?

Comment: no storyboard. all code. I do not know either. The code works fine if its done in a work flow without leaving the app. I open a turn, I play it. I push the nav controller to a third view to submit a new turn. then i pop back to the beginning. If I leave the app at all while on the third controller, when I come back, and try to pop back, it briefly dismisses and then, reloads a new instance of VC3 and displays it. I feel it 100% has to do with memory and the parent controllers deallocating - I just wonder if I should be referencing something more or what I can do to prevent this.

Comment: The parent view controller, if by that you mean the window's root view controller, shouldn't ever be deallocated, unless the app is killed. Even if it were, I can't see how that would cause a new instance of VC3 to be created. How are you pushing VC3 in the first place? Are you doing that from VC2?

Comment: yes i am. creating it and pushing it from the self.navigationController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68285/discussion-between-tjandadayy-and-rdelmar).